Add Tooltip with Full Column Name in Shiny `pickerInput` Dropdown
I am building an R Shiny application where I use the pickerInput() function (from the shinyWidgets package) to allow users to select columns from a dataset. However, if the column names are longer than 20 characters, they are truncated with ellipses (...). Here's a simplified example of my code:
library(shiny)

col_names <- c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
               "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
               "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc")

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
    "all_cols_id",
    NULL,
    choices = col_names,
    selected = NULL,
    options = shinyWidgets::pickerOptions(
      actionsBox = TRUE,
      size = 10,
      selectedTextFormat = "count > 0"
    ),
    multiple = TRUE,
    choicesOpt = list(
      content = stringr::str_trunc(col_names, width = 22)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Currently, the dropdown items display truncated column names. I want to add a hover feature where the full column name appears as a tooltip when the user hovers over a dropdown item.
How can I implement this feature in the pickerInput dropdown?

This question is similar to: Adding a different tooltip to each pickerInput option with shinyBS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also related: Add text on hover to selectInput/pickerInput choices (R Shiny).
